# Using keywords argument to query in GAE ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I met some problems when I would like to query the ndb on GAE.

Is it possible to query the db using keywords argument?

From the document, it shows that the query string should be expression.

```
qry = Account.query(username == 'test_user')
```

Can I query or filter by a keyword argument like

```
search_userinfo(username='test_user')

def search_userinfo(self, **kwargs):
    return UserInfo.query(**kwargs)
```

If not, how can I transfer the keyword argument into the expression that match ndb's condition.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will turn your kwargs into filters for the query:

```
def search_userinfo(**kwargs):
  qry = UserInfo.query(*(getattr(UserInfo, k)==v for (k,v) in kwargs.items()))
  return qry
```

Comment: get the Query object successfully, how can I get the value from the query result?. It raises an error when I use `qry.username`

Comment: Call .get or .fetch on it to return one item or a list of items.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the query should have the class name before the property name:

```
qry = Account.query(Account.username == 'test_user')
```

Next, the query uses the `==` operator while the `**kwargs` uses the `=` operator, so you'll have to write the query out yourself:

```
def search_userinfo(self, **kwargs):
    return UserInfo.query(UserInfo.username == kwargs['username'])
```

If you want to query on a list of properties, you could chain them together like this:

```
def search_userinfo(self, **kwargs):
    qry = UserInfo.query()
    if 'username' in kwargs:
        qry = qry.filter(UserInfo.username == kwargs['username'])
    if 'other' in kwargs:
        qry = qry.filter(UserInfo.other == kwargs['other'])
    ...
    return qry
```

See [NDB Query Class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass) for more details.

Comment: it's seems a standard way to query, but is there any general way to query? or needs to write the specific query code for each type or query?

Comment: @Greg has a one-line solution that converts a Python dictionary into an NDB query.  This answer gives you the option of customizing the query with other `filter()` types, `order()` clauses, etc., depending on the `**kwargs`.